# /usr/local/bin/perl5: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: perl, unix, tcl

I have a unix command 
(script)  which has a nested perl script in it.
when i run this unix command from command line it works fine.
If I am running same command from a tcl file using exec, i am getting following error:

```
'sh: /cmdpath/cmd.pl: /usr/local/bin/perl5: bad interpreter: Permission denied'
```

Any Idea what could be causing this. My tcl code is trying to execute this command several times ( more than 100 times).

Thanks
Ruchi

Comment: You would get more helpful help if you told us what the line of code to invoke the Perl script says…

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly your Perl script is encoded in DOS/Windows line-ending format, which uses `\r\n` to terminate lines.  Since Unix terminates lines with `\n` only, the `\r` is interpreted as belonging to the executable name, so that the kernel tries to run a program named `perl5\r` and fails.

Deleting the trailing `\r` on this line should fix the problem.

Alternatively, it may be that the `perl5` executable either does not exist at the given path, or exists but lacks the execute permission bit.  If you have this executable living somewhere else in the filesystem, update the path on the first line of the script to point to it.  To fix the latter problem, run

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/perl5
```

You will need to be root to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the output you are showing, you are likely executing "sh cmd.pl". In turn, sh is trying to execute the perl interpreter.
Why not spawn   "/usr/local/bin/perl5 cmd.pl" directly, this will be more efficient, especially if you are doing that hundreds of time.

Comment: I am running unix command sh cmd which is internally calling cmd.pl. also in cmd.pl I am mentioning the perl interpreter as #!user/local/bin/perl5. If i run from prompt it works well but if run the same sh cmd from tcl, it is giving me error and that too random in nature

Comment: What if you replace #!/usr/local/bin/perl5 in the first line of your script (assuming you have it) with
     '#!/usr/bin/env perl5'